# How to compare using base class in derived class data

Tags: c++, c++11

I have base class and derived class in C++.
I want to determine if the data of the derived class is the same using the pointers of the base class.

enum type

```
enum class FruitType: int{
    Apple,
    Orange,
};
```

base class

```
class Base{
public:
    Base(FruitType t): fruit_type(t){}
    FruitType fruit_type;
};
```

derived class

```
class Apple : public Base{
public:
    Apple(int i): Base(FruitType::Apple), foo(i){}
    int foo;
};
class Orange : public Base{
public:
    Orange(float f): Base(FruitType::Orange), bar(f){}
    float bar;
};
```

initialize

```
// initialize
std::vector<Base*> fruit_list_ = { 
                new Apple(42),
                new Orange(0.f),
                new Apple(1) };
```

Is there any way to check with HasSameData()?

```
Base* HasSameData(const Base* pCompare){
    for (const auto& list : fruit_list_) 
    {
        if( pCompare->fruit_type == list->fruit_type ){
            // how to check same data...?
            if( /* ... */ ){
                return list;
            }
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}

int main(){
    // check same data
    Base* pCompare = fruit_list_[2];
    if(HasSameData(pCompare)){
        // I want to return fruit_list_[2] pointer...
    }
}
```

Comment: [`std::type_info`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info) is what you need

Comment: @djacob Homemade reflection can build a bridge between C++ and other languages. In this case, there is only C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an abstract method `sameData()` to the base case

```
class Base{
public:
    Base(FruitType t): fruit_type(t){}
    FruitType fruit_type;
    virtual bool sameData(const Base& other) const = 0;
};
```

Override in the derived classes:

```
class Apple : public Base{
public:
    Apple(int i): Base(FruitType::Apple), foo(i){}
    int foo;
    virtual bool sameData(const Base& other) const {
        const Apple* apple = dynamic_cast<const Apple*>(&other);
        return apple && apple->foo == foo;
    }
};

class Orange : public Base{
public:
    Orange(float f): Base(FruitType::Orange), bar(f){}
    float bar;
    virtual bool sameData(const Base& other) const {
        const Orange* orange = dynamic_cast<const Orange*>(&other);
        return orange && orange->bar == bar;
    }
};
```

And use it as follows:

```
// how to check same data...?                                       
if( pCompare->sameData(*list) ){
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use a virtual function to compare equality and implement the comparison logic in the body of the virtual function.

```
class Base{
public:
    Base(FruitType t): fruit_type(t){}
    FruitType fruit_type;

    virtual bool Equals(Base *other) const = 0;
};

class Apple : public Base{
public:
    Apple(int i): Base(FruitType::Apple), foo(i){}
    int foo;

    bool Equals(Base *other) const override {
        if (other->fruit_type != FruitType::Apple)
            return false;
        return foo == ((Apple*)other)->foo;
    }
};

class Orange : public Base{
public:
    Orange(float f): Base(FruitType::Orange), bar(f){}
    float bar;

    bool Equals(Base *other) const override {
        if (other->fruit_type != FruitType::Orange)
            return false;
        return bar == ((Orange*)other)->bar;
    }
};
```

Then write your comparison function like this:

```
bool HasSameData(const Base* pCompare){
    for (const Base *fruit : fruit_list_) 
        if (pCompare->Equals(fruit))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```